# Common term for .net and mono

Tags: .net, mono

I'm going to teach basics of C# programming and I would like to keep it framework agnostic.
I'll be using terms like *Common Language Runtime* and *Base Class Library*, but I can't find a term that wraps those.

IMHO .net points to Microsoft and framework is too generic term.
Is there any appropriate term to describe both .net and mono?

Comment: On the Mono site they state it is "open-source .NET"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd still call it the .NET framework. [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) is just an open source version of the .NET framework, as it says on their website.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [Common Language Infrastructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure):

> The **Common Language Infrastructure (CLI)** is an open specification developed by Microsoft and standardized by ISO and ECMA that describes the executable code and runtime environment that form the core of the Microsoft .NET Framework and the free and open source implementations Mono and Portable.NET. The specification defines an environment that allows multiple high-level languages to be used on different computer platforms without being rewritten for specific architectures.

Edit: On second thought, while this includes the runtime, the executable format and the type system, this says nothing about the BCL.

Answer (score 1):

[Common Language Infrastructure (CLI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure)

> The Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) is an open specification
>   developed by Microsoft and standardized by ISO and ECMA that
>   describes the executable code and runtime environment that form the
>   core of the Microsoft .NET Framework and the free and open source
>   implementations Mono and Portable.NET.

The CLI specification describes the following ... aspects:-

- The Common Type System (CTS)

> A set of data types and operations that are shared by all
>   CTS-compliant programming languages.

- Common Language Specification (CLS)

> A set of base rules to which any language targeting the CLI should
>   conform in order to interoperate with other CLS-compliant languages.
>   The CLS rules define a subset of the Common Type System.

Answer (score 0):

.net runtimes?

I can't really think of anything better as microsoft .net is the windows runtime for .net, mono is the cross platform implementation of the .net platform. You also have the compact framework and micro framework as well as the silverlight runtime.